# Railway or Railways? Airway or Airways?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I see both of those examples.

Say, from COCA -

> *These special carriages were made especially for the London Necropolis **Railway** and painted chocolate brown, edged in an orange-red vermilion, to match the carriages of the London and South Western **Railway**, upon whose tracks the LNR ran.*

We have [Indian Railways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Railways) but is it 'Railway**s**' as it is divided into Southern Railway, Northern Railway etc. so collectively Railways? What if there are no divisions?

Same with 'Airways' *(in transportation only)*.

Please answer in *this context* only, I know pretty well that the singular form is used when the word is a collective noun.

Comment: Note that [British Rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail) is the new British Railways!

Answer (score 1):

[airway](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airway) is a designated route along which airplanes fly from airport to airport, especially such a route equipped with navigational aids.

An airline is normally a company that operates flights on several different airways, and so it is normal to incorporate **airways** (plural) in the title.

When railways were starting out in the UK, people set up a company to raise capital for a single line- for example, the Great Northern Railway built a line from London to York. The successful ones then started adding branch lines. By 1914, there were over 120 different companies.

When the railway network was nationalised in 1948, the  organization that managed this collection of lines was called British Railways.

Similarly, a [waterway](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/waterway) is a narrow area of water, such as a river or canal, that ships or boats can sail along. The organization that manages the canal network in the UK is called British Waterways.

Answer (score 0):

"Indian Railways" and "Ministry of Railways" are brand name of Indian railway system. While mentioning "railway" generally, it should be mentioned as "railway". But if you wish to say about railway system of India, you have to say "Indian Railways".

For your clarification see below quoted sentence, which is extracted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Railways).

> **Indian Railways** (reporting mark IR) is an Indian state-owned enterprise, owned and operated by the Government of India through the **Ministry of Railways**. It is one of the world's largest ***railway*** networks comprising 115,000 km (71,000 mi) of track over a route of 65,808 km (40,891 mi) and 7,112 stations.

Comment: One of the world's largest ***railway networks*** is beyond any doubt...you cannot have railways there!

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think the plural has anything to do with *brands*. Check this -*and hygiene, and joined hobo unions, to ensure peaceful relationships with the **railways.***